# Timer tick events does not fire in a backgroundworker do_work

Tags: c#, timer, backgroundworker

I have a background worker which i am using to perform some task. Its working as expected. However, i have a timer that i want to add and make it start the bw and counting like 10 seconds after page load. I put my timer.Interval to 10000. the timer has a tick  events as below

```
 private DateTime dateETA;
    private void TimerEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                while (bw.CancellationPending ==false)
                {
                    if (timerPro.Enabled == true)
                    {
                         dateETA = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/0001 00:00:00");
                        dateETA = dateETA.AddMilliseconds(timerPro.Interval);
                        lblETA.Visible = true;
                        lblETA.Text = "Elapsed Time : " + Convert.ToString(dateETA.TimeOfDay);
                       // SetText("timer");
                    }
                }
            }
```

My background worker async is on the page contructor method and therefore run on load. just like below

```
  if (bw.IsBusy != true)
            {
                this.btnPause.Enabled = true;
                this.btnStop.Enabled = true;
                btnStart.Enabled = false;


               // timerPro.Start();
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();

            }
```

I wanted to start the timer together with my task therefore i put it before my bw.async . Then i realized the timer tick events does not fire when put before or within the dowork method of the background worker. I thought may be the bw thread is blocking the event from firing then i use an invoke method like below within the dowork in my attempt to start the timer or trigger the tick event of the timer.

```
 this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { timerPro.Enabled = true; }));
```

It still does not fire. I am confused and any help or alternative would be appreciated.

Comment: what the he*l are you doing in the `if` clause in the `while` clause ?! what are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: Sorry. I want the time to stop as soon as the bw stops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want a running elapsed timer while the backgroundworker does its thing?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch SW = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timerPro.Interval = 1000;
        timerPro.Tick +=new EventHandler(TimerEventHandler);
        SW.Start();
        timerPro.Start();
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void TimerEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblETA.Visible = true;
        TimeSpan TS = SW.Elapsed;
        string elapsed = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", TS.Hours.ToString("00"), TS.Minutes.ToString("00"), TS.Seconds.ToString("00"));
        lblETA.Text = "Elapsed Time : " + elapsed;
    }

    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // ... do some work ...
    }

    private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        timerPro.Stop();
    }

}
```